# How to convert text into float in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, m

I have a column with coordinates in this format POINT(2.150423 48.786381). I want extract latitude and longitude because otherwise i can't see my points in the Map.

I tried the following m and DAX codes but it doesn't work even though i have a float in return. I dont understand.

```
= try Number.FromText(Text.Trim(Text.BetweenDelimiters([geo], "POINT(", " "))) * 1.0
```

m Error : Sorry... we cant proceed to the conversion into a number

```
= try Float.From(Number.FromText(Text.Trim(Text.BetweenDelimiters([geo], "POINT(", " "))))
```

m Error : Float.From wasn't recognised

```
LatitudeFloat = 
VAR startPoint = FIND(" ", 'Table'[geo], 1, LEN('Table'[geo]))
VAR latitudeText = MID('Table'[geo], startPoint + 1, LEN('Table'[geo]) - startPoint)
RETURN
    IF(
        ISBLANK(latitudeText),
        BLANK(),
        VALUE(
            SUBSTITUTE(
                SUBSTITUTE(latitudeText, ")", ""), 
                ",", "." 
            )
        )
    )
```

Dax error : impossible to convert value   « 48.782894 » of type text into number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use power query to clean the column. I would extract the text between delimiters
[image]
Then, I would split the column by the ' ' delimiter. Then you should be able to change the datatypes to numeric. (You may need to trim before that step if you're having problems.)

Lastly, after the data is loaded, assign the lat and long as their proper categories in the Data category back in Power BI Desktop
[image]

Comment: I did extract text between delimiter, split by delimiter space, trim data, also tried clean data but i have the same error "Sorry cant proceed to conversion into a number  "

Comment: I said nothing it works ! even though data is still text, i can see my data in the map thanks you :D

Comment: You may have the wrong regional setting where it thinks '.' should be ','. For example, in Europe, they use commas instead of periods. Go into File > settings > Current File - Regional Settings > and make sure it is English (United States)

Comment: Yes i had figured it out but it took me a lot of time ! still thank you zach !